# SharePoint 2013 Online (Office 365) create site error

Tags: sharepoint, creation, office365

I ran into a problem when programmatically creating a new site in SharePoint Online. I try to run it from a webpart. On-premise everything is working like a charm, but when I deploy it to SharePoint Online it generates an error occasionally. If I change the site name in my textbox after I get an error and retry, it works well.

I get the following exception:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The Web site address
>   "/nederlands/blablablablalblasd" is already in use. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 0x800700b7The Web site
>   address "/nederlands/blablablablalblasd" is already in use. at
>   ..............

The webpart has to create a site and create a group for the site. Group members are populated from listitems. The code I use is:

```
        using (SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site)
        {
            using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                try
                {
                    SPWeb site = null;
                    uint lcid = currentWeb.Language;
                    string templateName = "WIKI#0";
                    site = currentWeb.Webs.Add(siteName.Text, siteName.Text, siteDesc.Text, lcid, templateName, true, false);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    DebugUsingLiteral(exception.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: That's a huge amount of code. It'll help if you could post only the relevant sections, and not code that does parsing etc. That kind of steals away the real intent of the problem, and is very distracting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited the code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up by switching from a webpart to an App. In my opinion SharePoint 2013 Online and CSOM is a much better combination.

It also gives yout the ability to debug your solutions in the SPOnline environment.